# Concatenate the result of a query into a variable in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

Is it possible to concatenate the result of a query into a variable in postgresql?

Something like this in MSSQL:

```
DECLARE @Names_tmp NVARCHAR(max);

select @Names_tmp = 
COALESCE(@Names_tmp + ' UNION ALL ', '') +
FromTable.Name
from FromTable
```

FromTable structure:

```
Key     Name     Other Columns ...
1       name_1   asd
2       name_2   asd
3       name_3   asd
```

`PRINT CAST(@Names_tmp AS NTEXT)`

*result*:

```
name_1 UNION ALL name_2 UNION ALL name 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `STRING_AGG`

```
[SQL Fiddle][1]
```

**Query 1**:

```
select string_agg(name,' UNION ALL ') as res from t
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/605749/3/0)**:

```
|                                      res |
|------------------------------------------|
| name_1 UNION ALL name_2 UNION ALL name_3 |
```

Answer (score 3):

I see no need to use `plpgsql` for this matter. PostgreSQL [**aggregate functions**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-aggregate.html) should do it:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t (id INT, name TEXT, asd TEXT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,'name_1','asd'),
                     (2,'name_2','asd'),
                     (3,'name_3','asd');

SELECT ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(name),' UNION ALL ') FROM t;
SELECT STRING_AGG(name, ' UNION ALL ') FROM t;
```

Result:

```
------------------------------------------
 name_1 UNION ALL name_2 UNION ALL name_3
(1 Zeile)
```